# formatting a number in vba

Tags: vba, numbers, format

How do I format the output number to a specific number of decimal places in VBA?

I have

```
Label5.Caption = ((a^3)-(pi*((b/2)^2)*a))*c & Format(Label5.Caption, "##0.00")
```

but this is not working.  What is the correct way to format it?

Thank you

Comment: what value in your `Label5.Caption`? and what decimal separator do you use `.` or `,`?

Comment: how is it now working, what does it output.

Comment: I figured it our this is the right way:Label5.Caption =  Format(((a ^ 3) - (pi * a * ((b / 2) ^ 2))) * c, "#####00.0000#")

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 Dim strTemp As String

 Range("A1").NumberFormat = "0.000" 'or any other format you need
 Cells(1, 1) = 4 ' the number you want
 strTemp = Range("A1").Text
 Label5.Caption
```